# VS Code ignores Java formatter XML file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm trying to get the VS Code Redhat Java formatter (from the "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" extension) to work with a custom .xml, but nothing seems to work. I've tried:

- setting "java.format.settings.url": "D:\Others\formatter.xml" in the workspace (.vscode) settings.json file
- setting it in the global settings JSON
- restarting VS Code and reloading the window
- placing the file in %APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\User and using a relative path in "java.format.settings.url"
- placing the file locally in .vscode
- used "file:" when specifying the path

The formatting is always the same, regardless of the settings in the XML file. The base XML file is the one mentioned here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting. Am I missing something?

Comment: What formatting did you modify? What special settings have you made? Please provide more details.

Comment: I have changed everything from "do not insert" to "insert" just to check if anything changes, but nothing happens no matter what I change

Answer (score 1):

It seems that double backward slash `\\` should be used as the windows path splitor. So your setting should be `D:\\Others\\formatter.xml`.

Besides, the path which is relatd to the workspace folder is supported, e.g., `.vscode\\formatter.xml` points to profile `formatter.xml` in `.vscode` folder from workspace folder. No need to use URI format.

I suggest to use command `Java: Open Java Formatter Settings` to automatically generate a formatting profile for you. After that, you can find it in workspace (if exists) settings.json. If you want to custom formatter rules, just to replace the content in that file.

Comment: I have also tried double backward slashes and it does not work.